# How to make an index with md5 and concat_ws?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

How to make an index with md5 and concat_ws?

```
CREATE INDEX psn_prev_work_hash_idx ON public.psn_prev_work (CAST(md5(concat_ws('_|_', id, end_date)) AS uuid));

SQL Error [42P17]: ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

Version PostgreSQL 9.6.11

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.6 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: The index seems quite strange to me. What problem are you trying to solve with that, that an index on `(id, end_date)` can't solve?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `end_date` is a `date` column there is no easy way to create an index on that expression as all conversions from `date` (or `timestamp`)  to a text (or varchar) value are volatile due to the possible influence of locale or time zone settings.

As you know your expression is immutable (assuming `end_date` is indeed a `date`!) you can create an immutable function that you can use in the index:

```
create function make_uuid(p_id int, p_date date)
returns uuid
as
$$
  select CAST(md5(concat_ws('_|_', p_id, p_date)) AS uuid);
$$
language sql 
immutable;


CREATE INDEX psn_prev_work_hash_idx 
  ON psn_prev_work (make_uuid(id, end_date));
```

However, to make a query *use* that index, you need to use the function in your query, not the original expression:

```
select *
from psn_prev_work 
where make_uuid(id, end_date) = ...;
```

---

As a side note: the index seems strange to me. I can't imagine a situation where an index on `(id, end_date)` wouldn't be a better alternative.

Comment: I correctly understood that the select will look like this
 'select *
    from psn_prev_work
    where make_uuid(id, end_date) = 268bf985-b0b3-4805-ad9b-c0eb221396cf;' ?